# Not being given enough information to do task

Tags: communication, contractors

I work for a staffing/marketing agency as a contractor (I actually work for several but this question focuses on one in specific). I have never met any of the people I work with in person, only through email and over the phone. I find the way they communicate very difficult to understand. They had sent me a large container full of assets which now need to be returned. They are not providing me with clear instructions on how to do this and the deadline has almost passed.

They sent out a mass email with a bunch of instructions that don't apply to me (for example apply for assets I was never given) at at the bottom have

> 1. Call UPS at 1-800-PICK-UPS® (1-800-742-5877) and tell them you want to schedule a package pickup and that you have a Waybill, or visit your
>      local UPS store
> 2. Drop off the package
> 3. Send us a confirmation the package(s) have been sent

This is nonsense as I don't know what a Waybill is and was never given an address to ship to. I feel like the people I'm dealing with are being purposefully unhelpful. I'm not getting paid to wait on hold with UPS or do any of this and at this point I've spent more time then what I've gotten paid.

What's the best way to reply?

> I would like to do this but need more clear instructions.

Comment: Are you sure you are not taking part in a scam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, ask for clarification.

So ring them asap and try and get what you need, and also email your contact there so you have a paper trail. It pays to be careful when dealing with assets you don't own.